# Eclipse Regex Search and Replace Swap places

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, replace

I have code like this all over my class:

```
if (src.getTYPERECORD().getACT().equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
```

Now it can crash if the getters return null, and for the team's Best Practices, I was asked to convert it into:

```
if ("B".equalsIgnoreCase(src.getTYPERECORD().getACT()))
```

I have come up with the following regex for search for the easier case of where I already had the value assigned to variable like act.equalsIgnoreCase("B"):

```
(\w*).equalsIgnoreCase\("(\w*)"\)
```

Replace with:

```
"\2".equalsIgnoreCase(\1)
```

Which works except for the cases mentioned above, AND this:

```
tos.substring(1,1).equalsIgnoreCase("A")
```

Could you please help come up with the search and replace regex to catch the two examples mentioned above?
It would need to account for situations where the opening IF bracket is adjacent, and where there is a space like if ( src.... or if (src....

Thanks!

Comment: `"something".equals(something)` might hide bugs. I hate this approach, I prefer dealing with `null` separately.

Comment: Possibility of nesting suggests that this task shouldn't be done with regex but possibly with parser.

Comment: @Pshemo - What do you mean with parser? can you refer me to one suitable? or how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: @MarounMaroun - I dont like this approach either, but this is what the Team Leader requires, and how the rest of the code is written, its non negotiable, they call it "Best Practices" hehe

Comment: If you want to find parts like `foo.bar().baz.equals("someString")` then we can try regex here (it will not be easily for instance because of Strings like `"abc"+"bar"` or `"abc\"def"`, but it may be possible with regex). But problem starts if your code will contain nested expressions inside `(..)` like `foo.bar(someExpression(otherExpression())).baz.equals("someString")` because Java doesn't allow recursion in regex engine and Eclipse is written in Java.

Comment: So just like XML can't be properly parsed with regex, you should start looking for a tool which can parse Java code and create some kind of tree of expressions which you then search, remodel and generate code from it. I never used any Java parser so I can't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing like this should work :

```
\b([\S]*?).equalsIgnoreCase\("(\w*)"\)
```

Take a look at the example [here at rubular](http://rubular.com/r/VsLrWFeYs8) .

Comment: It doesnt match properly, try out your suggestion on this:http://rubular.com/r/PZqKDdRi17
(examples dont include a substring case which I found only later)

Comment: @Carmageddon Take a look at the updated answer, and thanks for pointing me to rubular(it is fantastic online tool) !

Comment: Thank you so much! this works very well, except this case: tos.substring(3, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("R") but I will take care of it manually, its rare. And glad to hear that you found something useful from this as well :)

Comment: Interestingly, it does not match this: src.getTYPERECORD().getNC().equalsIgnoreCase("TX--")

Comment: @Carmageddon for the last example is just because the \w doesn't include the dash, so change like this : \b([\S]*?).equalsIgnoreCase\("([\w-]*)"\) , while for the previous one is just because you have a space in the arguments, remove the space and it will work ....

Answer (score 0):

Java 8's `Optional` to the rescue!

```
if (Optional.ofNullable(src).map(Source::getTYPERECORD)
    .map(TypeRecord::getACT).orElse("").equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
```

If anything is null along the chain, including `src` itself, the `orElse()` fires and the test will be false. Otherwise, the test works as expected.

Comment: I appreciate the desire to help and give alternative suggestions to what have been asked, but there are reasons.. the project works on Java 1.6, I cant change that, and I cant get them to change the standard - I clearly stated this, and that I need to replace my own expressions... so please, give the solution to the problem, without suggesting solutions I cant use.

Comment: @Carmageddon OK. But you have my sympathy. Java 1.6 is coming up for its 10th birthday. That's *really* trailing edge...

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
Search: if\s*\(\s*(src.*)\.equalsIgnoreCase\((.*?)\)
Replace: if (\2.equalsIgnoreCase(\1)
```

Tested in Eclipse.